# FilterPattern of FilterLogEvents does not pick the string explicitly

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

With this code, and using the `FilterLogEvents` function I am getting the logs from `Cloudwatch` that match these parameters:

```
{
    "endTime": number,
    "filterPattern": "string",
    "interleaved": boolean,
    "limit": number,
    "logGroupName": "string",
    "logStreamNames": [ "string" ],
    "nextToken": "string",
    "startTime": number
}
```

The code:

```
response = self.cloudWatchLogs.filter_log_events(**kwargs)
```

I defined filterPattern to be "`ERROR`" so that I can get all the error logs. My problem is that I get also other logs with the string : `INTERRORESEAU`. I set the filterPattern to "`.ERROR:`" but I still get the fake errors. How to tell the filterpattern to pick only and explicitly `ERROR` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter pattern should be :

```
 kwargs['filterPattern']='".ERROR:"'
```

Like that you make sure you are picking the exact error word.